# How to change the color of a Bootstrap popover in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this JS code to bring up a popover:

```
$('a').popover({content: 'Popover text', title: 'Popover'});
$('a').popover('show');
```

I would like to change the attributes, for example, I would like the color of the popover to be a light yellow.  Is there a way I can do this in the JS code itself?  Perhaps in the template option?

Comment: Have you tried `$('a').popover().css("param", "value");`?

Comment: What would be the param/value pair? I've tried `$('a').popover().css(".popover-title", "background:#ffff99");` and `$('a').popover().css("popoverBackground", "#FFFFE0");` with no luck.  (PS, I'm a total bootstrap newb)

Comment: I mean something like this: `$('a').popover().css("background-color", "#ffff99");`. Take a look at this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: That changes the color of the element (in my case a button) not the popover itself

Comment: [You can change the default template of the popover:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414468/6933766)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with CSS by using the `.popover`, `.popover-title`, and `.popover-content` classes.

```
.popover-title{
    background: #ffff99;
}
```

Comment: Ah ha, I got this working.  `.popover-header{
    background: #ffff99;
}

.popover-content{
    background: #ffff99;
}`  Thanks!

Comment: Only problem is that this affects all popovers.  How can I accomplish the same thing for a specific popover?

Comment: Give the popover's parent container another class:  `.popover-container>.popover-title{background: #ffff99;}`

Comment: @Korra You could also put a class on the element or use the element type that generates the popover like this: `a ~ .popover{background: #ffff99;` or `a ~ .popover > .popover-title{background: #ffff99;`

Comment: it should be    background: #ffff99 !important;

Comment: This doesn't change the color of the popover arrow

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out, the way to change the popover color is to change the CSS of `.popover` and `.popover.right .arrow:after`. But since we want this to happen dynamically, we would do:

```
$('.popover').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.popover.right .arrow:after').css('border-right-color', 'red');
```

**But wait, the second jQuery snippet is not right.** You cannot have `:after` selector because `:after` is NOT a part of DOM, hence no javascript in this world will be able to catch `:after`. So I made this CSS.

```
.popover-danger {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
    color: white;
}

.popover-danger.right .arrow:after {
    border-right-color: #d9534f;
}
```

And whenever I need to change the color of my popover, I write the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('#selector').next('.popover').addClass('popover-danger');
```

The `#selector` is the element on which you have applied the popover. From that element I search the next `.popover`. This ensures that we are dealing with the popover attached to the current element only. Then we simply add the class so that the `:after` selector can be applied naturally without JS.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/t9tpk3j7/)

Comment: This is the best option, create diferent popover classes for each contextual class in bootstrap

Comment: Oh, and use these colors: div.popover-danger {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #dca7a7;
    color: #a94442;
}

Comment: Also be aware of the arrow, because each direction has its own class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to change background color of the Popover title bar and the full Popover:

```
$('.popover-title').css("background-color", "#9FC53B");
$('.popover').css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
$('#username').popover({
  title: '',
  content: 'error!'
  });
$('#username').popover('show');
$('.popover').addClass('popover-danger');
```

html:

```
<div id="username" class="input-group" data-html="true" data-placement="right">
  <span class="input-group-addon width-100 align-right">Username=</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" title="username" placeholder="Enter username..." v-model='username'/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.popover-danger {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap 5.2, popovers can be [customized with CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#variables).

```js
new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle=popover]'));
// initialize
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.my-popover {
  --bs-popover-bg: lightyellow;
}
</style>
<button class="btn btn-primary" 
  data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-custom-class="my-popover"
  data-bs-content="This is the popover content.">
   Click for Popover
</button>
```