# Bootstrap tooltip arrow border and background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I change the background color and border color of the tooltip arrow? I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
.tooltip-main {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #737373;
  color: #737373;
  margin: 4px 121px 0 5px;
  float: right;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.tooltip-qm {
  float: left;
  margin: -2px 0px 3px 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 236px !important;
  height: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border: 1px solid #737373;
  text-align: left;
}

.tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Hello world"><span class="tooltip-qm">?</span></div>
```

Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/DXTLRSDHcc

The difference between that post and this post is to identify how to change the border and background color of the arrow itself and not the toop tip. all of the answers shows that you put a border-top-color to achieve different color for the arrow. but I want to achieve different border color + background color of the arrow itself

Comment: Please don't type entirely in uppercase letters, there's really no reason to ever do this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another pseudo element that will cover the first one and you translate it slightly to create the needed visual

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
.tooltip-main {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #737373;
  color: #737373;
  margin: 4px 121px 0 5px;
  float: right;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.tooltip-qm {
  float: left;
  margin: -2px 0px 3px 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 236px !important;
  height: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: left;
}

.tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::before,
.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before {
  border-bottom-color: #f00!important;
  /* Red */
}

.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 0 .4rem .4rem;
    transform: translateY(3px);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Hello world"><span class="tooltip-qm">?</span></div>
```

Comment: I have added your extra code but it doesn't seem to change anything.

    .bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::before,
    .bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before {
     border-bottom-color: #f00!important;
     /* Red */
     }

.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 0 .4rem .4rem;
    transform: translateY(3px);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}

Comment: @IbadullahKhan then check the order of the CSS you added and clear your cache

Comment: I think this code is for tooltip bottom. I'm using tooltip top.

Comment: can you please help me with the on-going issue? I'm normally not aware of this positioning in CSS. Can you tell me how will I position "top"? Like I suppose this is for [x-placement^=bottom] bottom.

Comment: @IbadullahKhan can you share the code with the "top" position, so it's easy for me to help?

Comment: @IbadullahKhan and what is the issue? seems like the same tooltip as here

Comment: I want the arrow to be like this: http://prntscr.com/mjkd9u. White arrow with border-shadow on it. Whereas the sample link I've posted above shows the arrow in black with no shadow.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work doing something similar to what [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) suggested. However we ended up changing over to using popovers instead so we could apply a `popover-box-shadow`. Bootstrap popovers are just like tooltips except they come with a border so none of that fussing with the overlapping arrows was necessary. Plus when using scss you can do the vast majority of styling just by modifying the variables.scss file.

In order to change the background color of the popover see this answer: [Change bootstrap popover background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490989/change-bootstrap-popover-background-color)

Comment: Absolutely agree, the popover, when used without a title, is just a much better solution thanks to those SCSS variables. Great suggestion

Comment: The only difference between a popover and a tooltip, outside of visual styling is the popper.js trigger of `click` vs `hover focus` Technically if you wanted a popover to work like a tooltip you could just initialize it and override the trigger property.